# What is the $k-$th derivative of $ \frac{1}{1-x^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$. How to find the $k-$th derivative of $f(x)$?

I thought it's an easy application of Taylor series.

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^2}=\sum x^{2k}$$.

On the other hand,

$$f(x) = \sum \frac{f^{(n)}}{n!}x^n$$

So I thought I just need to compare each terms. For example,

$$\frac{f^{(2)}}{2}x^2=x^2\Longrightarrow f^{(2)}=2$$

So I concluded that

$$f^{(2n)}=(2k)!,f^{(2n+1)}=0$$

But the solution gives me

$$f^{(n)}=\frac{n!}{2}\left( \frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}}+\frac{(-1)^n}{(1+n)^{n+1}}\right)$$

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: The power series gives you a formula for $f^{(n)}(0)$, and assuming that the last term of the last line should be $\frac{(-1)^n}{(1+x)^{n+1}}$, the two answers agree.

Comment: When using Taylor's theorem to say that $f(x) = \sum \frac{f^{(n)}}{n!}x^n$, you're missing one important point: The $f^{(n)}$ is really $f^{(n)}(0)$.

Comment: While there are elementary ways to tackle this specific problem, a general approach to finding the derivative with respect to $x$ of the composite function $f(g(x))$ is given by the [Faa di Bruno Formua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faà_di_Bruno%27s_formula).  That approach is overkill here, but it is a useful-to-know approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating derivatives of $f(x)$ directly is rather messy (except at $x=0$). So as the 'answer' indicates, you should first rewrite $f(x)=\frac12 \left( \frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{1}{1-x}\right)$ as a sum of two simple fractions for which derivatives are easy to calculate.

Comment: I was struggling to come up with a quick way to do this. +1